# How to capture a GET call using Ruby (Watir/WebDriver)?

Tags: ruby, rest, watir, watir-webdriver

On the webpage I am testing, a GET call is made when the user clicks an option in a select list.  The GET looks like this:

```
GET /mediaportal/captions/SCH/Follow%20Up%20with%20the%20Robles%20Family_SCH.xml
```

How can I tell Ruby to listen for the GET request and capture it, or more specifically capture and put into a variable the url that is requested in the GET above.

(*I'm using the watir-webdriver gem, I'm hoping there is something in there that would allow me to do that.*)

Comment: seems unlikely that you can do that with watir. I haven't used it myself but it looks like a black box tester. To capture the GET request (that I guess is made by a script on the page?) you would need to inject javascript into the site somewhere between the option click and the GET post. Not easy. (Another far way to go is to set up a sniffer (wireshark is one) for the URL at hand and listen to it for request. I have no idea if there are Ruby interfaces for those things.)

Comment: I wonder if there are any gems available that would enable me to listen for REST requests (GET, POST, etc.)?

Comment: The problem with 'listening' for such requests is it requires getting down into the network stack, or setting up some kind of proxy.  Tools like wireshark or fiddler2 would let you do and are useful for manual testing, but trickier to integrate into automation.  Still some kind of proxy is going to likely be your best solution

Comment: @froderik, yes Watir drives the browser the way a user would, so in that sense it is somewhat 'black box' I can of course see a lot of details of the HTML and objects in the DOM that a user can't see without viewing source or using a developer tool like firebug, so there's a lot of validation that can be done at that level, but once you pass below the level of the DOM, such as the HTTP traffic itself, it is pretty much blind.

Comment: indeed - an alternative for urbanaut may be to make sure the url he wants to put in a variable actually turns up in the DOM somewhere. (guessing it is somewhere in javascript state as matters stands now) had a similar problem myself when testing a vaadin application - form widget state were kept in javascript and not visible in the DOM.

Comment: Fiddler2 is what I used to capture the GET request I included with my question.  Great program!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - I did a little bit of more research and it turns out that there is a HTTP proxy thing bundled with the webrick web server. (A common experience with Ruby - the solution is often closer than expected.) The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902427/ruby-how-to-catch-all-http-traffic-local-proxy) sums it up nicely and points towards [a blog post](http://altentee.com/blogs/2008/httpwatch-a-free-alternative-using-ruby/) that gives a code example for how to do it.

You start a server using WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer and then you should be able to intercept all traffic. A challenge may be to interact with this server from your test code. It may be hard to do this without setting up some kind of server. But if you just want to listen for a specific call then you could start the server as part of your test suite and then shut it down when the call appears.

Comment: Thanks, great resources. Now I just have to figure out how to get WEBrick to pipe the traffic into a continuous string and save it into an array or something, then scan the text, regex it for the GET request, and and pop that into a new variable.

Answer (score 5):

Try net/http gem:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://yoursite.com/mediaportal/captions/SCH/Follow%20Up%20with%20the%20Robles%20Family_SCH.xml ')
Net::HTTP.get(uri) # => String
```

For more info, try here: 
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Comment: I think he wants to listen to requests rather then initiating them.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, and an interesting solution for this (in the previous answer) .. Also, as said in above comments, later on net/http requests could get intercepted by fiddler, or any other http sniffing software .. Well, as what concerns - watir-webdriver gem, there is nothing there that would support such functionality as far as i know ..

Comment: correct, watir cannot 'see' the http traffic.  Most things can't unless they are generating the requests and receiving the responses.

Answer (score 3):

I think having the http traffic going through a proxy is likely to be your easiest way to deal with this.  That or ignore the api behind the curtain for functional level tests, and focus on whatever happens in the UI when it gets the response from that request.  Write seperate API test automation that works at the API level if you need to test a REST api itsef.

This [gist of an http proxy server](https://gist.github.com/74107) might be something you could work from

If you want to testa REST API directly, I recommend using the [REST-Client](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/rest-client) gem.  If the traffic is in JSON format, the [JSON-spec gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec) is also a lifesaver especially if you need a great library for rspec/cucumber validation steps (.should matchers and cucumber 'then' steps.)  [I gave a presentation](https://github.com/watir/watir-bazaar/wiki/Presentations) on using cucumber and those two gems for API testing at the Test Automation Bazaar.. my first time presenting this stuff, (I should have found the time to make slides, but hopefully what is there will give you at least a rough idea of how to start.)

Comment: Sounds like a proxy will be what I need to use.  In my last script I did end up using open-uri and json to get additional information I needed for a similar test.  Great presentation by the way. Upvote for the helpful ideas.